# Count distinct ids based on sum of columns

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have the feeling this should be really simple but can't get my head around it, I'd appreciate any advice on the following (which I've simplified to focus on what I can't do). I'm using Azure SQL.

I have a table of results (called testanswers) as follows:

```
id | PupilId | NumMark
----------------------
1  | 10      | 1
2  | 20      | 2
3  | 10      | 2
4  | 20      | 0
5  | 10      | 1
6  | 20      | 2
```

I would like to count the number of pupils (i.e. distinct PupilId) who have achieved a number of marks between two boundaries.

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PupilId)
FROM testanswers
WHERE SUM(NumMark) >= 2 AND SUM(NumMark) <= 5
```

The error message says

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

I'd appreciate any suggestions about how to code this query correctly.

Thanks,

Steph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the `SUM(NumMArk)` for every pupil, you have to `GROUP BY PupilID`:

```
SELECT PupilId, SUM(NumMark)
FROM testanswers
GROUP BY PupilId ;
```

To then keep only the rows where this sum is between `2` and `5`, you can use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT PupilId, SUM(NumMark)
FROM testanswers
GROUP BY PupilId 
HAVING SUM(NumMark) >= 2 AND SUM(NumMark) <= 5 ;
```

If you then want to count how many pupils pass this condition (and not show their IDs), you have to wrap the above in another query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS result
FROM
  ( SELECT PupilId
    FROM testanswers
    GROUP BY PupilId 
    HAVING SUM(NumMark) BETWEEN 2 AND 5 
  ) AS tmp ;
```

---

This would also work in SQL-Server - but not sure about the Azure version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () AS result
FROM testanswers
GROUP BY PupilId 
HAVING SUM(NumMark) BETWEEN 2 AND 5  ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac241/2)**

Comment: Thanks for your very complete explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(PupilId) AS NUMBEROFPUPILS
FROM (SELECT PupilId FROM testanswers GROUP BY PupilId HAVING SUM(NumMark) BETWEEN 2 AND 5) AS TEMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PupilId)
FROM testanswers
Group by PupilId Having SUM(NumMark) >= 2 AND SUM(NumMark) <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

See with data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff287/1

Try a group by

```
SELECT  PupilId
FROM testanswers
group by PupilId
having SUM(NumMark) >= 2 AND SUM(NumMark) <= 5
```

But also looks like your table is missing an attribute - or have you not put it here as its not relevant?

Comment: Won't that give the same error? It's still using aggregate functions in the WHERE clause without it being a subquery.

Comment: changed it and sample - sql fiddle is a cool tool. made the table by copying your sample and replacing | with , then using their wizard     Text to DDL

Comment: @tgkprog You can also use the "Text to DDL" function! (and note that the question is about Azure, a version of SQL-Server, not MySQL.)

Comment: i do not think there is any difference - group by is part of ansi sql. supported by all RDBMS

Comment: anyway you got it right earlier i see by stamps and got the data base right too so up-voted u :) maybe the question asked will mark it as the answer too.

Answer (score -2):

try `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT SUM(NumMark),COUNT(DISTINCT PupilId)
FROM testanswers
GROUP BY SUM(NumMark)
HAVING SUM(NumMark) >= 2 AND SUM(NumMark) <= 5
```